# no source attachement for javax.persistence

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working on a maven project, trying to use eclipselink as a jpa provider and I alwaays get the same thing, eclipse can't find jar javax.persistence.jar :
Source not found.
the jar file ....\javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar has no source attachement

while the jar file already exists, I don't know if I have to move it to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to see contents of classes from javax.persistence.jar. or you might be performing debugging operations.

You mostly gets this error if jar don't have java files in it. These kind of jar only consists of .class files when they are packaged.

Otherwise you can download and include JPA jar from following location:
http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.persistence&version=2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Download source for the jar, unpack and when you get the Exception, click on "add source" and locate the downloaded folder.